# Embed emberjs application into static site henerator hexo.io

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hexo

I have an hexo.io application where I'm rendering a lot of html from markdown files.
I need to embed an emberjs application into the static html generated files.

**Test 1.**

- Use ember build command with --output-path to generate app files to the js include folder for hexo.io
- Include the files {applicaiton}.js & vendor.js in hexo.io theme template
- Generate the static html files

***Results***

- **OK** ember js files where loaded correctly
- **Error** 
  `Uncaught Error: Could not read config from meta tag with name "spa/config/environment".`

**Test 2.**

- I include the head meta tag from the index.html of the ember-cli app into the template

`meta name="spa/config/environment" content="%7B%22modul..."`

This is the config enfironment.js url encoded

**Results**

- Now I can see the emberjs application detected

`DEBUG: -------------------------------`

`vendor.js:15751 DEBUG: Ember      : 1.11.1`

`vendor.js:15751 DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.16.1`

`vendor.js:15751 DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3`

`vendor.js:15751 DEBUG: -------------------------------`

`(program):66 Ember Inspector Active`

- The ember inspector is note detecting the application
- This error is also throwed
  `Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError: /stati-file.html`

Now I'm stuck on:

- Fix the UnrecognizedURLError.
- Properly detect the ember app in ember inspector.
- How to include the emberjs outlets in my static html files template.

Comment: This could be a bug ([see](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3416)). Perhaps canary should already be fixed. Also, the error thrown says "**stati**-files.html", is that correct or is it a typo?